# Find & Replace Multiple Sequence Headers in Multiple FASTA Files

Tags: bash, macos, sed, replace, find

Here's my problem (using a Mac OS X):

1. I have about 35 FASTA files with 30 sequences in each one.  Each FASTA file represents a gene, and they all contain the same individuals with the same sequence headers in each file.  The headers are formatted as "####_G_species," with the numbers being non-sequential. I need to go through every file and change 4 specific headers, while also keeping the output as 35 discrete files with the same names as their corresponding input files, preferably depositing the outputs into a separate subdirectory.

   For example:  Every file contains a "6934_Sergia_sp," and I need to change 
   every instance of that name in all of the 35 files to "6934_R_robusta."  I need to do the same with "8324_Sergestes_sp," changing every instance in every file to "8324_P_vigilax."  Rinse and repeat 2 more times with different headers.  After changing the headers, I need to have 35 discrete output files with the same names as their corresponding input files.
2. What I've found so far that seems to show the most promise is from the following link:
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files

   using the following script:

   ```
     find /home/user/directory -name \*.c -exec sed -i "s/cybernetnews/cybernet/g" {} \;
   ```

   Changing the information to fit my needs, I get a script like this:

   ```
   find Path/to/my/directory -name \*.fas -exec sed -i 's/6934_Sergia_sp/6934_R_robusta/g' {} \;
   ```

   Running the script like that, I get and "undefined label" error.  After researching, 
   https://www.mkyong.com/mac/sed-command-hits-undefined-label-error-on-mac-os-x/

   I found that I should add '.fas' after -i giving:

   ```
   find Path/to/my/directory -name \*.fas -exec sed -i '.fas' 's/6934_Sergia_sp/6934_R_robusta/g' {} \;
   ```

   because on Macs you need to specify an extension for the output files.  Running the script like that, I get very nearly what I'm looking for with each input file being duplicated, the correct header in each being correctly substituted for the new name, and the outputs being placed in the same directory.  However, this only substitutes one header at a time, and the output files have a .fas.fas extension.

Moving forward, I would have to rename the output files to remove the second " .fas " in the extension, and rewrite and rerun the script 3 more times to get everything changed how I want it, which wouldn't be the end of the world, but definitely wouldn't be ideal.

Is it possible to set up a script so that I can run all 4 substitutions at the same time, while also exporting the outputs to a new subdirectory?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Mac `sed` will accept `sed -i '' 's/.../.../' file` (that is two single quotes), to indicate no backup file to be made, just overwrite existing file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good, but I would prefer a more verbose approach where I don't have to fight so much with the quotes. Something like:

```
for fasta in $(find Path/to/my/directory -name "*.fas")
do
    new_fasta=$(basename $fasta .fas).new.fas
    sed 's/6934_Sergia_sp/6934_R_robusta/g; s/Another_substitution/Another_result/' $fasta > $new_fasta
done
```

Here, you fed the list of FastA file to loop over, you compute a new fasta name (and location, if needed), and finally run `sed` over the input and leave the output in a new file. Observe that you can give more than one substitution in `sed`, separated by semicolons.

BTW, as @Ed Morton said, for the next question please, include a concise description of the problem and sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it out, but I get an error message back:  "sed: 1: "s/6934_Sergia_sp/6934_R ...": invalid command code _"  It creates the new fasta files, but they are empty.  I've tried to include my script, but I can figure out how to format my post so that it's not a giant blob of text.  With that said, can you think of a reason why I'm getting that message?  Thanks again

Comment: No idea. The `sed`commands for substitution are of the form `s/original/substituted/`, and you can separate a bunch of them with semicolons. Did you wrote exactly my command? Can you give me the full error message? You should put your code in the original question so everybody can see it and help you.